# Probability Combination with Groups

Tags: probability, statistics

I am stuck on this particular problem. I am supposed to find the number of different possible combinations.

I have 5 groups and in each group, there are 4 choices. I have to choose only one item from each group. So I know that each final combination would have only 5 items in it. So I am unsure if I am doing my work correctly, but I was thinking that I would do it as follows:

4*4*4*4*4 = 1024

Is this the correct method for determining all possible combinations from 5 groups with four options taking only one item from each group?

Thank you,
Daya

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Comment: It is correct .

Comment: Does this take into account that I can't have any repeated groups. As no two groups would ever be the same?

Comment: Your answer only works if all groups are distinct. As in, each group has 4 unique members that are not present in any other group. If any member is duplicated within a group or in a different group, you would be counting some combinations multiple times and would need to modify your answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Fortunately, all of my groups are distinct.